# gnuplot: numerical values of points of a function

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible with gnuplot (4.6) to print (in a file or through redirection from standard output) the values of the sampled points of a function.

Say, if I write `plot sin(x)` with for example `set samples 20`, I want 20 lines of data giving me the x,y values of the computed points that would be plotted.

I don't care if these are actually plotted or not.

I though that there was some kind of "text" terminal, but it seems that there is none.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `set table` environment

For example:

```
set table "outputfile.txt"
plot sin(x)
unset table
```

Comment: Thank you, this was actually so simple but somehow I managed to miss the "table" sub-command! Well, actually, maybe I missed it because finding it isn't that obvious...